# Move or copy files of certain type from subdirectories of same name

Tags: centos, find

I need to pull all mp4 files from a set of directories with the following type of structure.

```
Jan
    -Folders
      - -888
      - -777
Feb
   -Folders
     - -888
     - -777
```

Basically what I need to do is put all the mp4's from the -888 folders in one new directory, all the mp4's from the -777 folders in another new directory and so on.

I tried pulling all the mp4's for all the directories (thinking then I could split them out from there) into a single folder with the following command:

```
find /myfiles/folders/ iname "*.mp4" -type f -exec /bin/mv {} /videos \;
```

This did pull all the mp4 out of my stacks of folders but instead of putting them in the videos directory that I had created, it instead merged them all in a single file called videos.  Would love to know what I missed in the script to not make that happen again!

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: For one thing, you are missing a hyphen at the start of `iname`.  Is that how you actually ran the command?

Comment: And did you really create `/videos`? Or did you accidentally typo?

Comment: How did you get two subdirectories with the same name? You could always temporarily rename(mv) and then switch it back after.

Comment: If `/videos` doesn't exist, that would move all files to that name one-by-one, destroying all but the last. I wouldn't call it merging, though.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  Answers:I did have the hypen - that was just a typo.  I did have a folder called videos to move them into.